# Is Google Sheet Pivot Table Generally Slower Than QUERY Function? What are the best practices?

Tags: google-sheets

It seems that the GOOGLE SHEET Pivot Table is slower than running a QUERY function. Does anyone know if it's true? Is is generally better to use QUERY then Pivot Table?

My Pivot Table draws on about 8000 rows 26 cols across, which also has about 4-5 calculated fields. Is Query generally faster than Pivot Table? Since PT is a bit easier to make than complicated query functions. Not sure if the PT's slowness is due to calculated fields.

Are there any good/best practices?

Comment: in my humble opinion, yes, QUERY is faster

Comment: I've been trying to measure the difference by using Apps Script. No significant difference so far (I'm trying to see if I've mode something wrong). When you say if it's slower, you mean to update when changing the values in the data range, right?

Comment: Thanks both. PT slows when data is updated and when the Sheet is first opened.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get the timing by using Apps Script shows no significant difference between those methods. This means probably means that all the changes are due to the frontend. There are no official best practices for front end efficiency, but in general trying to not have massive amounts of data is important. To handle big amounts of data is actually better to use other services more specific for this cases (which one would depend on how you would use it).